# silviomoreto bootstrap-select style broken in version 1.13.1

Tags: bootstrap-select

After upgrading **bootstrap-select.min.js** version from **1.12.4** to **1.13.1** all height style of controls on my site are broken. The height is properly styled if I include 1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js but not 1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js

- All CDNs are from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs.
- I am using Bootstrap 4

### Upgraded includes

```
bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css         
// controls height is broken when using this include
bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js            
ajax-bootstrap-select/1.4.3/css/ajax-bootstrap-select.min.css
ajax-bootstrap-select/1.4.3/js/ajax-bootstrap-select.min.js
```

### Downgraded includes

```
// bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css        
// controls height working when using this line with upgraded includes
bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js      
// ajax-bootstrap-select/1.4.3/css/ajax-bootstrap-select.min.css
// ajax-bootstrap-select/1.4.3/js/ajax-bootstrap-select.min.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have specified HTML5 using `<!doctype html>`.
See [Different height of select with HTML5 and Bootstrap Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277514/different-height-of-select-with-html5-and-bootstrap-select) for the more detailed answer